# PyQt4 with PyQwt5 : ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 n est pas une application Win32 valide

Tags: winapi, pyqt4, importerror

I have this problem, (it's been 2 entire days now and I cannot solve it).

I have this Python Error :

```
File "C:\Users\Maxime\Documents\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\Qwt5\__init__.py", line 32, in _load_dlls
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 n�est pas une application Win32 valide.
```

I'm trying to use the PyQt4.Qwt5 library and i have no idea why it's not working. I tried to download and install both 32 (PyQwt-5.2.1-py2.7-x32-pyqt4.9.6-numpy1.7.1.exe) and 64 bit (PyQwt-5.2.1-py2.7-x64-pyqt4.9.6-numpy1.7.1) files from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ but it doesn't work. I need this library to use de Qwt Graphs.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I was running python 32 bit on a 64 bit machine. I uninstalled python, numpy, and pyQt (which were in 32 bit) and I installed python 64 bit, Numpy 64bit, PyQt4 64 bit and now PyQwt works fine !